# Activate all windows from background when clicking on main window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an Objective-C application with a main window and a small progress window with a stack view to show the current progress.

If the application is put in the background by activating any other application and then clicking on the Dock icon, both the Main and secondary windows is brought to the front and shown.

But, if I just click one of the windows when in the background, only that window is activated and brought to the front, the other stays in the back.

I want to implement so that when I click on the main window it does the same thing as clicking on the Dock icon, it should show both windows on top with the Main window activated.

But if I click on the progress window, I don't want the main window to be brought to the front.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this, how should I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect the window being clicked with the window delegate's [`-windowDidBecomeKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowDidBecomeKey:) or `-becomeKeyWindow`, or the app delegate's [`-didBecomeActive:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive:).

Then depending on your exact needs, you can use [`[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/activateIgnoringOtherApps:) or [`[[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] activateWithOptions:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRunningApplication/activateWithOptions:) (and possibly `NSApplicationActivateAllWindows`).

Comment: Thank you, this is was what I was looking for. A small question, when testing [[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateAllWindows], no window became key, and the main window I use could not become key unless i clicked on a secondary window first. I've already implemented what I needed, but that was just a question if there is something more to that. Didn't see anything in the docs.

Comment: When you say "could not become key", did you try calling `-makeKeyAndOrderFront:` manually? It's possible (likely) that is distinct from `activateWithOptions:`.

Comment: I tried this:

    [[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateAllWindows];
    [_window becomeKeyWindow];

Comment: You shouldn't call `becomeKeyWindow`, you should call `makeKeyWindow`. Or `makeKeyAndOrderFront`. Also, you might want to switch the order of those two calls (not sure, I haven't tried).

Comment: Yeah, the problem was i tried it in  -windowDidBecomeKey:, when moved to  -windowDidBecomeMain it worked as expected. It was looping in setting and becoming key. Thanks for your replies, now it's working as I want it!